# Proof: Finite product of elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to proof the following theorem:

Let $A,B \in M_{mxn}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B$ is $A \sim B$ (equivalent of rows with $A$), then there exist a matrix $C \in M_{m}(\mathbb{R})$, such that $B = CA$, where C is the product matrix of a finite number of elementary matrices of order $m$.

I would appreciate if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the row-reduced form of $A$ and $B$.  We can represent the row reductions on both matrices by some $C_1$ and $C_2$, which are product matrices of elementary $m\times m$ matrices, so that we have:
$$C_1A = C_2B = D$$
Now, since they're the product of elementary matrices, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are invertible.  Thus, we may write $$B = C_2^{-1}C_1A$$
Then we can let $C=C_2^{-1}C_1$, and since $C$ is invertible it can be written as the product of elementary matrices.

Comment: Can be proof without row-reduced methods?